# Is this a counterexample for topology being generated by basis?

Tags: general-topology

In Munkers' Topology the book is trying to prove that the topology generated by bases are actually a topology. For "the union property" it says:

> Now let us take an indexed family ${\{U_\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$, of the elements of $T$ and show that $$U= \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha$$ belongs to $T$. Given $x \in U$, there is an indexed $\alpha$ such that $x \in U_\alpha$. Since $U_\alpha$ is open there is a basis element $B$ such that $x \in B \subset U_\alpha$. Then $x \in B$ and $B \subset U$, so that $U$ is open, by definition.

I think this doesn't work for the following collection of sets, since although by the argument in mentioned text (brown page above) says that it must be a topology but it's not since ${\{a,b}\}$ is not in $U$ but ${\{a}\}$ and ${\{b}\}$ are in $T$.

[image]

Where I am wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: You are not considering topology generated by basis elements ${a}, {b}$. Basis by themselves don't form a topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding that paragraph. That paragraph says that the union of open sets is still open with respect to the topology generated by your basis. Indeed, since each element of {a,b} is contained in an open subset {a} and {b}, {a,b} itself must be an open set under the topology generated by {a} and {b}.

Comment: But {a,b} is not open in the figure!

Comment: If your topology is generated by {a} and {b}, it must be open. So the diagram doesn't represent the topology generated by {a} and {b}.

Comment: The diagram's bases are {a}, {b} and X={a,b,c}.

Comment: Then by the definition of open set, {a,b} is open since each element of {a,b} is contained in an open subset.

Comment: But it is not open in the figure. No circle around a and b together. Meaning any open set predicted by bases may not be in T so the two definitions are not equivalent.

Comment: Because your figure is not the topology generated by {a},{b} and {a,b,c}. In the first sentence of that paragraph, Munkres says ,"Let us check that the collection T generated by the basis B is, in fact, a topology on X."

Comment: Is this correct? : Independent of the first definition of topology given in Munkers' book, we define a 'concept' with bases and we then prove that this concept is same as the first definition of topology given without defining bases. The topology generated by {a},{b} and {a,b,c} is {{a},{b},{a,b}{a,b,c}} and {{a},{b},{a,b}{a,b,c}} is topology by the definition before introducing "basis". And it doesn't apply for the mentioned figure since it is not a topology from the basis def so is not topology as the first def.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct. It didn't apply here because that figure is not the topology generated by {a},{b} and {a,b,c}.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot :-)